# Borders Function not stopping sprites from getting out

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, border

First of you should know, the area where the player is allowed to play in is a square, that is 320x320 which is centered in the screen. That 320x320 square is a 5x5 grid [64x64 each tile], and the player is always centered in the tiles of the grid.

When the player moves, no matter the direction, its always a 64 pixel move.[1/5 of the grid's size].

```
func move(node: SKSpriteNode, direction: String) {
//'node' determines what spritekitnode to move. 
//'direction' classifies which statement to run.
    if node.name == "player" {
        if direction == "left" {
            if node.position.x - 64 >= map.position.x - 160 {
            //Checks if the Node can move without 
            //moving off the grid [map, the 5x5 grid].
                node.runAction(moveLeft)
                //Moves the Node
            }
        }
        if direction == "right" {
            if node.position.x + 64 <= map.position.x + 160 {
                node.runAction(moveRight)
            }
        }
        if direction == "up" {
            if node.position.y + 64 <= map.position.y + 160 {
                node.runAction(moveUp)
            }
        }
        if direction == "down" {
            if node.position.y - 64 >= map.position.y - 160 {
                node.runAction(moveDown)
            }
        }
        if direction == nil {
            print("[move() function] : No direction specified!")
        }
    }


}
```

My problem, is when the player spams or quickly presses the button to move multiple times 
consecutively, the player ends up being able to move off the grid.

Example, when the player is on the bottom tile of the 5x5 grid, and moves down 2 times fast
enough, the player goes off the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `RunAction` does not remove the previous action, so when they spam,  they queue up multiple actions to run concurrently.  You need to either have your move functions not allow the bounds to be broken, or call `removeAllActions` before you run a new action